# How to exit sub when filepath is not found?

Tags: excel, vba

I’ve been trying to educate myself on VBA for a while now by reading through your forum and hope you can now help me with an error I couldn’t find the solution to.

I’m trying to save a workbook when closing. The file path is a mapped drive, however, the file might be used by people without the access rights to that drive. Therefore I want the macro to do nothing when the file path is not found and simply exit the file. This is where I get the runtime error. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim OrigName As String
    Dim FolderPath As String

    OrigName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    FolderPath = "\\MappedDrive\Folder1\Folder2\"

    If Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FolderPath + ActiveWorkbook.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs OrigName

    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

The code works fine when connected to the drive but once disconnected I get the error message for the following line:

```
If Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
```

> Message: Runtime Error 52: Bad File Name our Number

As mentioned, If the file path cannot be found I want the code to abort and close the workbook, as if there was no macro existing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be more exact about what the error message is and where it is.

Comment: [Edit] your question including the message and what line of code it errors on. Don't put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could try using error handling:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim OrigName As String
    Dim FolderPath As String

    OrigName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    FolderPath = "\\MappedDrive\Folder1\Folder2\"
    on error goto finish
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FolderPath + ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs OrigName
    on error goto 0
    ' continue code here if you need to do more

finish:
    ' you can add code here that will be performed if the error occurs

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed a neat solution and works perfectly, just tested it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the **expected functionality** of `Dir` for a Drive that does not exist:

```
Debug.Print Dir("\\ValidDrive\ValidFolder", vbDirectory)
'Result: "ValidFolder"

Debug.Print Dir("\\ValidDrive\InValidFolder", vbDirectory)
'Result: ""

Debug.Print Dir("\\InValidDrive\InValidFolder", vbDirectory)
'Result: Runtime Error 52: Bad File Name our Number
```

Either use FileSystemObject, or `On Error` to catch these cases.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense, I just wasn’t familiar with this function. Thank you for the explanation.